# Hovering a decluttered label in open layers

Tags: openlayers

I've recently used the declutter feature for labels in openlayers 4.5 and it works great. However, the hover event I have still fires when a "decluttered" label is moused over. Is there a way I can tell if a label has been turned off by decluttering? I can't seem to find a property or setting that has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There was a bug](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/7474), which was [solved](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v4.6.0) with the version 4.6.0 that was released yesterday. Just upgrade to the latest OpenLayers version.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try today and if it works I'll accept the answer.